# Why are the rig controllers at the bottom of the character feet not correctly aligned correctly with the feet. Please refer the file attached

Tags: mesh, rigging

I am new to blender. Have been learning the different controls and options. I want to create this rig with my own character to create short animations.

I have used basic human meta-rig and fit it to this character and generated the rig. After that i assigned the rig to the mesh with Automatic weights. But the rig controller at the bottom of the legs are not at place, directly within the foot, as i see is the case with rigs online. Can someone please tell why the rig controller is aligned like that.

Please find the file attached -
https://blend-exchange.com/b/kA3ZA3oa

Comment: You should provide screenshots of this issue. This kind of thing is easier to answer if we can clearly see what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but you can move the bones under the feet: Select the bones in Edit mode and move them down:

[image]

Also maybe select the custom shape and put the origin at its geometry (the custom shapes are in the collection called *WGTS_rig*, make sure that you've activated the *Disable in Viewport* option so that you can see the shape in the 3D view):

[image]